# Custom Attributes not returned in id_token

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I added some Custom Attributes to my User profile, and Claims.

When I examine the returned id_token, I can see some of the claimed values, but not my custom attributes.

Does anyone know why they are missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to have your custom attributes returned in the id_token, you have to configure that in the policy (`sign-in` or `sign-up or sign-on`). The policy is the place to define what claims should be provided to the application.

Read more about **build-in** policies here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies and pay attention to the `application claims` part.

P.S. Do not fall (yet) into the custom policies section. You do not need that.